# ThreeJS with panorama view

Tags: 3d, three.js, panoramas

First of all, what I want to do is to create a panorama view of a 3D model.

So what I need to do is:

1. Create the different pictures (Front, Left, Right, Back, Bottom, Top)
2. Load the pictures into a box
3. Visual it on the browswer

Every step at the moment is working just one step not as I want. The first step is my problem, I don't know how to calibrate or how to place the camera right that I don't see any corners in the panorama view. At the moment I see the box outlines very well.

So my question is: Can anyone tell me how to set the camera to make a good set of different pictures to combine them later to a panorama view?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/create-your-own-environment-maps/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're going to use a "real" camera and pictures or 3D renderings, but for rendering you should:

- render each side on a square texture
- set X and Y fov to 90deg.
- point the camera exactly along each axis: +X,-X,+Y,-Y,+Z,-Z

This way you should get 6 pictures that work quite well together.

If you want to do this for a "real" pictures, then you'll need some mapping from your distorted images to a cube map. This will depend on your lens, so it's not so easy; I think that professional apps for this task do this by comparing pictures, rather than just math.